# Add div above all divs with height between two divs matching data elements

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have table and td with numbers on them as div I want to add a div above all divs with height between matching date-numbers such as div should start 700 and end 800 above the divs under it. I use below code but it is adding between them.

```
  var htmlString = '<div class="stack-top ' + cssclass + '"><div class="mydivinside"><span class="stitle">' + title + '</span><br/><span>' + setime + '</span></div></div>',
  div = document.createElement('div'),
  div1 = document.querySelector("div[data-day='" + dateoffset + "'][date-tnumber='" + ehour + "']");
  div.innerHTML = htmlString;
  div1.parentNode.insertBefore(div.firstChild, div1.nextSibling);


 <td class="md" data-date="10/24/2022" data-day="0">
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="700" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="701" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="702" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="703" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="704" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="705" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="706" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="707" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="708" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="709" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="710" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="711" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="712" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="713" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="714" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="715" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="716" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
  <div data-day="0" date-tnumber="717" onclick="GetData(this);"></div>
</td>


CSS
    .stack-top{ z-index: 9999;  vertical-align:middle;  width: 80%; position: relative;}
```

[image]

Comment: From a programming point of view do not create objects until needed.  There is no reason to create 60 "minute" objects for each 1 hour row and then try to navigate where the appointment should appear.  For each hour you should retrieve the appoints, sorted by time, and then just create and insert them in order.

Comment: I did that but it does not show the true gap between appointments.

Comment: Visually that can be represented by absolutely positioning the appointment object at some calculated `top` based on the of the height of a relatively positioned container div within the 1 hr row block. For easy math lets say the height of a row is set as `height:120px`. Based on your image above a 7am appointment is at `top:0px` and the appointment object height should be calculated as set to 2px per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually that can be represented by absolutely positioning the appointment object at some calculated top based on the height of a relatively positioned container div within the 1 hr row block.

For easy math lets say the height of a row is set as height:120px.
In the example the duration of an appointment is in minutes.
A *factor* can be calculated by dividing the height by 60 (the number of minutes in an hour)

This *factor* is used to calculate `top` and `height` of the appointment so that it can scale to whatever height is set for the `.appointment-container`.

In this example I'm using `data-*` attributes to set appointment information.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".appointment-container").each(function(i, container) {
    let factor = Math.round($(container).height() / 60);

    $(this).children(".appointment").each(function(i, appointment) {
      let top = (appointment.dataset.start - container.dataset.start) * factor;
      let height = appointment.dataset.duration * factor;

      $(appointment)
        .css("top", `${top}px`)
        .css("height", `${height}px`);
    });;

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table>thead td:first-child {
  width: auto;
}

table>thead td,
table>tbody td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.appointment-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.appointment {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10pt;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Appointment<br>Schedule</td>
      <td>Tuesday<br>27-Sep-2022</td>
      <td>Wednesday<br>28-Sep-2022</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>7:00 AM</td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container" data-start="700">
          <div class="appointment" data-start="710" data-duration="10">Job 1</div>
          <div class="appointment" data-start="730" data-duration="20">Job 2</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8:00 AM</td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container" data-start="800">
          <div class="appointment" data-start="830" data-duration="60">Job 3</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9:00 AM</td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="appointment-container"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```